# Is it possible to run 2 main classes in one “Run Configurations” in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, program-entry-point, launch, multiple-instances

Is it possible to run 2 main classes with a small delay in one "Run Configuration"? Could I enter some parameters in the Arguments field? 
I have 2 classes, first of all I have to start class 1 so that class 2 can run.

I just want to put those processes together.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you implement this in a third class whose main method is implementing the call to the two other classes and the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script (e.g., in Ant) that launches both programs.  Then use the External Tools Configuration, not Run Configuration, to launch it.

[image]